# How can I configure IIS so that my ASP.NET web applications running on the same machine can POST to each other, but the public cannot POST?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, paypal, paypal-ipn

More specifically, I am writing a web request handler that forks requests to different processing pages for *separate, distinct* ASP.NET web applications. Specifically, this handler's purpose is for handling Paypal's Instant Payment Notifications.

I'd like to know how I can expose those custom processing pages to localhost only, so that my forking handler's POSTS will go through, but remote machines cannot post to those pages directly.

Answer (score 1):

IIS can be configured to only allow certain IP addresses to access a site.  These settings can be found on the directory security tab for the site (IIS6) or in the IP address and domain restrictions option (IIS7).  You can restrict this to local requests only be specifying the only allowed address to be 127.0.0.1

Comment: Is this only available at the site level or at the individual page level as well?

Comment: IIS handles this only at a site / application level - if you want to go more granular than this you'll need to build into your asp.net application, checking the Request.IsLocal property

Answer (score 1):

In IIS Manager, in the Bindings action panel for the site you only want to allow local access to, change the IP address to be 127.0.0.1.

For more than one application, set up several aliases in your Windows hosts file (system32\drivers\etc\hosts) for 127.0.0.1. Back on the Bindings action panel, set the hostname for each site to be one of those aliases, and use that alias in your GETs or POSTs from the other sites, such as httpx://mylocalsite/default.aspx.

If you can't isolate an entire site, then you can write an `HttpModule`, and in the `BeginRequest` event, throw an error if `Request.IsLocal` isn't true for the pages you're concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i do not know how to do it in IIS, but your pages can check

```
Request.IsLocal
```